# How to run python files packaged with in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox

Hello i am creating a bootstrap addon for firefox i need to run a python script to handle some task,can any one tell me how to execute the python file packaged with in the addon,so far i tried to execute the system command using the code below but it doesn't work ... i already googled a lot for this but can't find suitable answer.In the below script i tried to execute the file that is already on the system but it still don't work.

```
function startup(){

Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var env = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment);
var shell = new FileUtils.File("/usr/bin/python");

var filename = '/tmp/test.py'
var args = [file_name];

var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(shell);    
process.runAsync(args, args.length);
}
```

Thanks in advance.